# 2003 Dodge Caravan over-heating

Tags: dodge, overheating, caravan

My 2003 Dodge Caravan is over-heating.

I've changed the thermostat but this hasn't solved the problem. The upper hose on the radiator is warm (and appears to soften).

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/J6oNw.jpg)

What would be the next thing to check/replace?

Comment: Welcome to Motor Vehicle Maintenance & Repair! Could you explain the question you'd like us to answer for you?

Comment: My 2003 Dodge Caravan start over heating so I change the themostart and radiator cap it still over heat and when i feel the upper radiator hose it hot and feel like no water is going through the hose

Comment: Again, I'm not seeing a question. We want to help you, but you aren't telling us what you need help with. I'm not sure where you're going or what you'd like to know. All I can tell is you have an overheating problem.

Answer (score 1):

It wouldn't be hot if coolant wasn't running through it. So the question is: Is enough coolant flowing? That would be a water pump issue. Or, are the radiator fans not doing a good enough job. That would be a fan or fan relay problem. See [this article](http://ricksfreeautorepairadvice.com/car-overheats-chrysler-vehicles/) on Chrysler fan relays